# Every finite map is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to understand the proof of the theorem which states that every finite map is surjective in Shafarevich's book:

[image]

I didn't understand why the part underlined in red is true.

I need a little help here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use: $f^\ast(t_i) = t_i\circ f$

Comment: @Andrew yes, I've already tried this, but what means $t_i(f(x))=?$ I don't know how to evaluate this.

Comment: $t_i(f(x))$ is the $i^{\rm th}$ coordinate of the point $f(x)\in Y$. We are requiring that $f(x) = y$.

Comment: The statement you give without further hypothesis is incorrect. For example, any closed immersion is finite.

Comment: @Cantlog: I would say rather that Shafarevich's _definition_ of finite is incorrect.